# Apache CXF: Documentation for rest APIs

Tags: spring, rest, cxf

We use Apache CXF along with Spring for developing a web services application. Is there any way to generate all the end-points in the application as a document just using the built-in annotations?

I am looking for something like `rake routes` in the Rails world ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXF can automatically generate a service listing with links to [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) files, describing your web-services.

By default, if you have a REST web-service exposed at

```
http://host/path
```

going to

```
http://host/path/services
```

should give you that service listing.

To directly get the WADL document just add `?_wadl` to where your REST server is mounted. All the operations and methods available on this path and its children should be documented there.

See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html (section "Service listings and WADL queries" in particular).